# 7 zip command line equivalent to the explorer extension

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0, 7zip

I am looking for the 7-zip command line call that is the equivalent to the explorer extension option of `Add to "FolderName.zip"`:

[image: 7 Zip Explorer Extension]

I have tried:

```
& 7z C:\path\To\SecondAttempt, C:\path\to\SecondAttempt.zip
```

And I get the following

> 7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
>
> Command Line Error:
>   Unsupported command:
>   C:\path\to\SecondAttempt,

**Does anyone know the command line equivalent of the explorer extension for 7-Zip?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fo 7Zip this should be the correct syntax

```
 . .\7z.exe a C:\path\to\SecondAttempt.zip "C:\path\To\SecondAttempt"
```

But I would prefer to use directly .NET

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory("C:\path\To\SecondAttempt","C:\path\to\SecondAttempt.zip")
```

Comment: I would also prefer to use directly use .NET but that command (`-AssemblyName`) does not seem to work in Powershell 2.0

Comment: That first command is what I was looking for.  I was missing the `a` and had an extra comma.

Comment: If you can you upgrade to PowerShell 5.0 (5.1) it would be the best. 2.0 is default or Win 7 and I suggest to upgrade PS and .NET as well.

Answer (score 4):

The shell extension invokes `7zG.exe`, a GUI utility that shows a nice GUI window if this is what you were looking for. Using [SysInternal ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) it's possible to look up the command line used, basically:

```
& "C:\Program files\7-Zip\7zG.exe" a -tzip -slp- "a.zip" "file1.txt" "file2.txt"
```

- The file list can be put into a file and its name is specified after `@` instead of the file names.
- `-slp-` disables large page mode, and `-slp` enables compression speedup of large files